Parsing string values from example data
I am running on the latest version of Python BDD. When trying to parse example values from feature to Python it seems to only pick up the text in the feature "< feature >" and not the example data.
@given(parsers.parse("{parameters}"), target_fixture="parameters",converters={"parameters": str})
def ParseParmeters(parameters):
    return parameters

Feature file:
Found solution to my dumb problem add Scenario outline to Scenario line.

    Feature:check if data of given attributes is NOT NULL
        Scenario outline: Duplicate_check
            Given <parameters>
            When SQL to execute:
                SELECT  
                '%TST_CD' AS Test_Cd
                ,(select failurename from table where ='NO_ROWS_RETURNED'
                )  tst_SQL
                WHERE tst_SQL.tst_Result = 'Fail';
            Then EXPECTED_RESULT=NO_ROWS_RETURNED
    
            Examples:
            | parameters |
            | TST_CD=Duplicate_check;Data_Entity=LIT;PROCESS_NAME=procname;Data_Attribute=DA1,DA2;Proc_Typ_Cd=P3 |


Found solution to my dumb problem add Scenario outline to Scenario line

if you resolved your problem then you can put it as answer below. And you can mark it as accepted answer. And later you can upvote your answer.

Found solution to my dumb problem add Scenario outline to Scenario line.
Feature:check if data of given attributes is NOT NULL
    Scenario outline: Duplicate_check
        Given <parameters>
        When SQL to execute:
            SELECT  
            '%TST_CD' AS Test_Cd
            ,(select failurename from table where ='NO_ROWS_RETURNED'
            )  tst_SQL
            WHERE tst_SQL.tst_Result = 'Fail';
        Then EXPECTED_RESULT=NO_ROWS_RETURNED

        Examples:
        | parameters |
        | TST_CD=Duplicate_check;Data_Entity=LIT;PROCESS_NAME=procname;Data_Attribute=DA1,DA2;Proc_Typ_Cd=P3 

|
